# Adding a subtitle to TableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to display a subtitle to my table view, but I keep getting an error saying 'Assignment to readonly property' my code to deploy the text is

```
cell.textLabel.text = [arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel = [arraySubtitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

but on the 2nd line, I get the error! Please help me! Thank you! (objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign (may be a string) value to a label of `cell` rather than text (property) of label of cell.

try this....

```
cell.textLabel.text = [arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [arraySubtitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  // Update here, 

return cell;
```